# Mac App Rejected for Using Sandboxing Entitlement that I am Not Using

Tags: xcode, macos, appstore-sandbox

My Mac App Store app is being rejected under rule **2.31: Apps that are not sandboxed appropriately may be rejected**

They are saying that my app uses the entitlement ***com.apple.developer.maps***, but does not have *"matching functionality within the app."*

The problem is, NO WHERE in my project is the maps entitlement set.

I have tried several builds, so its not just a fluke.

I have checked the Capabilities tab of the target for my app and my helper app, and both are correct. I have checked the entitlements file for both the main app and the helper app and both are correct.

I also took the build that I submitted to Apple and ran: `codesign -dvvv --entitlements :- <fileName>` on the executable for both the main app and helper app and both came back with the correct entitlements.

I then went into the main folder for the app, in terminal, and ran: `sudo grep -i -r "com.apple.developer.maps" *` and NOTHING was found! To make sure grep would find what I am looking for, I also tried: `sudo grep -i -r "com.apple.security.files" *` and this did return the correct entitlement entry.

So as you can see, I can find NO WHERE that the com.apple.developer.maps entitlement is enabled, but Apple keeps rejecting me for having it enabled.

Has anyone ran into something like this before, or have any ideas of something I might be missing, or any other ideas on how I can debug this next?

Comment: Shouldn't you be discussing this with Apple? How is this a Stack Overflow question?

Comment: I have asked apple for help and gotten the response "make sure you are uploading the correct binary" so I am on SO looking for help from other devs who may have run into this issue or might have ideas.

Comment: Hello.  Has anybody found a workaround?  I'm hit with the same injustice for an entitlement that I don't have.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I wrote up a blog post that talks this issue and the solution. 
It was actually a follow up post to another fellow devs post as I wanted to make sure people didn't run into this exact issue.

You can find the blog post, which includes all the solutions on fixing the issue at: http://kdbdallas.com/2015/01/24/modern-login-items-gotcha/

That said the solution is close to what Jeffro said, but not exactly.

Comment: The link is still broken, it would be very interesting to see the solution.

Comment: The WayBackMachine has this URL cached: https://web.archive.org/web/20150131053259/http://kdbdallas.com/2015/01/24/modern-login-items-gotcha/

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem before.  I submitted an app that was rejected for using the entitlements maps.  However I never included maps in the entitlements file or capabilities.  The problem was not in xCode or the Entitlements file.  The solution is to go to the member center and check your Distribution Provisioning Profile for its App ID.  Then go to that App ID and disable Maps there.  This is one solution.

Comment: Does'nt work for me as there is no Maps entitlement for the app in Member Center either.